# I have a 15x15 matrix of 0s and 1s. How do I calculate the number of 1s in the entire matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I created a count variable which counts all the instances of 1 in the matrix d1 but I am not getting any value from `count`:

```r
d1 <- as.matrix(i1) 
count <- 0 
for ( i in d1 ) {
 if ( i == 1 ) 
 count++ 
} 
count
```

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, please post your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sum(d1)`. Note that `count++` does not increment `count` in R: it's a C or C++ operator, not available in R. Also avoid loops in R whenever it's possible.

If you want to count occurrences of the string `"1"` in a character array: `sum(d1 == "1")`.

Additional recommendation: now that you have stated that you array holds character data, it's not a very good idea to mix types in the test `i == 1` in your code. It should be `i == "1"`. As a matter of fact, in R, `1 == "1"` is true, so it's not really a bug, but it's extremely error prone.

Comment: Thank you, but the sum() function is not working as my variables are strings, not numeric. Do u know a method of counting the number of strings like "0" in the matrix?

Comment: @loop99 Edited. But you should have clarified this in your question, as it's nowhere stated that you are dealing with character strings.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

```
d1<-sum(lengths(regmatches(m1,gregexec("0",m1))))
```